# What are the differences between Jenkins cron syntax and the normal unix cron sytax?

Tags: jenkins, cron

There are loads of cron generators for the normal Unix cron jobs. We can easily create a cron sytax online using sites like: www.cronmaker.com

However, the output of these generators doesn't work in Jenkin's scheduler. Suppose I need to schedule a job twice a week, then how do I write the cron sytax for this? The normal cron sytax would have been :

```
0 0 22 ? * WED,SUN *
```

However, Jenkins refuses to accept this with the following error:

> Invalid input: "0 0 22 ? * WED,SUN *": line 1:8: unexpected char: '?'

What are the differences between Jenkins cron syntax and ordinary cron syntax? How can I convert from ordinary cron to Jenkins cron?

Comment: `?` isn't a valid range in standard cron, so not surprising Jenkins doesn't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

From the Jenkins help: `MINUTE HOUR DOM MONTH DOW` where `DOM` is the day of the month (1-31) and `DOW` is the day of the week (0–7) where 0 and 7 are Sunday.

You can write `0 0 * * 0,3`, and while editing the job's configuration Jenkins will suggest making that `H 0 * * 0,3`, where H means a hash value of the job's name (so that if you have multiple jobs that are scheduled to run more or less together they will spread across the hour).